# What are good and maybe free UI storyboarding applications, especially for mobile UIs

Tags: tools, interface-design, mobile

Hi I would like to get an overview of existing UI desktop or online application, which may have a specialization towards user interaction modeling and mobile device interfaces. I guess there are some applications out there which suit that constraints, but I just do not find them.  So please share your experience, which application do you use for developing (mobile device) UI storyboards?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you re-phrase this as more of a question?

Comment: if you go to UX.stackexchange.com you'll fine several long discussions on all the various wireframing and prototyping tools on the market. It's not really a good question for SE as it's mainly an opinion based answer. That said, my opinion is the same as Matt's. I don't believe wireframes should ever be electronic documents. You should go from paper sketches to working prototype code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pen and paper.** Can't beat it. Cheap, easy, effective. Incredibly fast. Just like they teach you in design school, you should be doing dozens, potentially hundreds of sketches to fully hash out an idea. It's an easy way to explore countless variations of an idea, even ones that you might have second guessed when used software. No need for producing "sketchy looks" that are meant to detach a storyboard from the real thing. This is as real as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for that input! I agree! But my question was ment to reflect those helpers, which ease that process, especially when you have to  sketch a lot of UI states!

Comment: You shouldn't be sketching a lot of UI states. At that point, you should be building a lot of UI states. ;)

Comment: I think the single biggest problem with using software for wireframing is that now they are suddenly 'documentation' that gets shared with stakeholders. And all-to-often the wireframes become *the* document or record which only snowballs problems down the road. Either you end up in a nightmare maintenance hell of constantly updating and synching the wireframes (which never happens) or the development team starts compromising the solution to bend the software to fit the wireframes (which happens way too often).